# Is it possible to iterate through a list of objects and do dynamic tests for each input?

Tags: tdd, cypress

I am currently learning cypress.io, and I have `7 checkboxes` representing each day of the week `Sun-Sat`.

```
    {days.map((day, idx) => (
        <input
            onChange={(e) => {
                const { checked, value } = e.target;

                    setDays(
                        days => days.map(data => {
                            if (data.id === day.id) {
                                return {
                                    ...data,
                                    id: value,
                                    select: !data.select,
                                };
                            }
                            return data;
                        })
                    );

                    setDayId(prev => {
                        return checked
                            ? [...prev, value]                  // add if checked
                            : prev.filter(val => val !== value) // remove if not checked
                    });

                    console.log("CHECKING CHECKED VALUE", e.target.checked);
                    // console.log("WHAT IS THE SET VALUE", values)
                }}
                key={idx}
                name={day?.name}
                type="checkbox"
                value={day?.id}
                checked={day.select}
                id="habit-frequency"
            />
        ))}
```

And I am trying to avoid doing this 7 times, because I am sure that there is a much better way to do it

```
cy.get("#habit-frequency")
            .should("have.attr", "name", "Sun")
            .should("have.attr", "value", "1");
```

I though about doing this:

```
const DAYS = [
    { id: 1, name: "Sun", select: false },
    { id: 2, name: "Mon", select: false },
    { id: 3, name: "Tue", select: false },
    { id: 4, name: "Wed", select: false },
    { id: 5, name: "Thu", select: false },
    { id: 6, name: "Fri", select: false },
    { id: 7, name: "Sat", select: false },
];

        DAYS.map(day => (
            it(`Should have a checkbox for ${day.name}`, () => {
                cy.get("#habit-frequency")
                    .should("have.attr", "name", day.name)
                    .should("have.attr", "value", day.id)
            })

        ))
```

But it isn't really working. Any advise? Here is the full test I have written so far in case it helps

```
describe("Create Habit", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit("/");
    });
    it("Should have a 'Habit' button which can be clicked to display a modal", () => {
        cy.get("#modal-btn").should("contain", "Habit").click();
        cy.get(".modal-title").should("contain", "Add Habit");
    });
    it("Should have a 'Add Habit' title, 2 inputs, one for name and one for description, a habit type option, a weekly frequency and an option to choose colors", () => {
        cy.get("#modal-btn").click();
        cy.get(".modal-title").should("contain", "Add Habit");
        cy.get("#habit-name")
            .should("have.attr", "placeholder", "Habit name");
        cy.get("#habit-description")
            .should("have.attr", "placeholder", "Habit description");
        cy.get("#habit-todo")
            .should("have.attr", "name", "To-Do")
            .should("have.attr", "value", "1");
        cy.get("#habit-nottodo")
            .should("have.attr", "name", "Not-To-Do")
            .should("have.attr", "value", "2");
        DAYS.map(day => (
            it(`Should have a checkbox for ${day.name}`, () => {
                cy.get("#habit-frequency")
                    .should("have.attr", "name", day.name)
                    .should("have.attr", "value", day.id)
            })

        ))
        
        cy.get("#habit-frequency")
            .should("have.attr", "name", "Sun")
            .should("have.attr", "value", "1");
        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because you are nesting `it` calls, Never nest them.
just use your code as is without the internal `it` call

```js
it(`Should have a checkbox for ${day.name}`, () => { /// this should be removed
..
}/// this should be removed
```